# Httpd integration with Tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, server, httpd.conf, tomcat9

I need to configure httpd with Tomcat. I tried few steps but it is not working.

1) I installed both httpd2.4 and tomcat9. Checked both individually with localhost:8080 and localhost and it works perfectly fine.
2) To configure, I did changes on httpd with below changes.

a) Uncomment below LoadModule

```
  LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
  LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
  LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
  LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
  LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
  LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
  LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

b) Added New Virtual Host

```
  <VirtualHost ws.foobar.com:80>
  ServerName ws.foobar.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /examples ajp://localhost:8009/examples
  ProxyPassReverse /examples ajp://localhost:8009/examples
  </VirtualHost>
```

3) Similarly, done the changes for Tomcat and umcommented AJP connector.

```
    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->

<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
           address="::1"
           port="8009"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

After doing these changes, I have changes th hosts file on my windows system as well.

```
  "# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
  # 127.0.0.1       localhost
  # ::1             localhost
  103.73.151.211    ws.foobar.com
   192.168.0.103    ws.foobar.com
    127.0.0.1      ws.foobar.com
     ::1            ws.foobar.com"
```

After doing all these changes My httpd.exe is not starting and tomcat starts but while starting giving error for AJP.

[image: Httpd.exe from cmd]

[image]

Comment: Please pay attention to the tags: You tag [tag:apache], which states that it's about _programming_ to httpd apis, explicitly _not_ about configuration (because that's off topic for stackoverflow). Also, you tag [tag:tomcat8], but mention to have installed [tag:tomcat9]. And please don't post text content as images. I'm voting as Off topic for stackoverflow (see [help/on-topic])

Comment: If this question closes, it can probably be asked on _Server Fault_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself has figured out the issue and how to configure Apache with tomcat.

I did the following changes :

1. uncommented LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so &
   LoadModule    proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so from the
   httpd.conf file
2. uncommented Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf, always in
   httpd.conf In httpd-vhosts.conf, I added as below.  Remove the space between "< V" as somehow without space it is not displaying here in stackoverflow.

   ```
   < VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass /  http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
   < /VirtualHost>
   ```